# How to call a function by array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a video playlist in array. I want to call a function (e.g. alert "Attention!") when selected videos/video.length are playing (e.g. 2ed, 4th, 8th ...). Any solution is appreciated. Use the complete [code from my JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nojava/bn4qm0L6/).

```
var videoSource = new Array();

videoSource[0]=''; 
videoSource[2]=''; 
videoSource[3]=''; 
videoSource[4]='';
videoSource[5]=''; 

var i = 0;
var videoCount = videoSource.length;
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]);
videoPlay(0);

function videoPlay(videoNum)
{
    document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
    document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if(i == (videoCount)){ i = 0; videoPlay(i);}
    else{videoPlay(i);}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `playing` event?

Comment: Since `play()` starts the video and returns (before the playing is ended), you could add the functionality directly after play() is called: https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/3/

Comment: `vidIndex % 2 == 0` checks if the remainder when dividing by 2 is 0. In other words if it's an even number. Just an example criterium really. To specify indices you can use something like: `if([1,3,4].indexOf(vidIndex) != -1)`  (https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/5/ ) . Or one step further, alter the source array so it contains information on what should happen on playing to have greater versatility

Comment: -1 is returned by `indexOf` if it can't find an index. so `!= -1` means it should not be -1, and thus it is inside the array. I've added an answer with some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code is not blocked when the video starts playing, the logic can be placed immediately after `play` is called.
The most simple way to check for indices is something like `if(index==1 || index == 3 || index == 4)`, etc, but a bit more maintainable is keeping it inside an array, such as : `if([1,3,4].indexOf(vidIndex) != -1)`. The array contains the indexes. `indexOf` returns the index inside the array, which is `-1` if it's *not* inside the array

An example using alerts: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/5/)

A bit more advanced use case, would be storing the url's inside objects where you can assign also specific meta data and behaviour to the objects. e.g.: [Fiddle with objects](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/6/)

Comment: `vidIndex` is shared between the methods (its so-called 'scope') and is increased inside the `myHandler` method: `vidIndex = ++vidIndex % videoCount;`  The `%` or 'modulo' operator makes sure vidIndex stays inside the videoCount range

Comment: The simplest way is to add `videoCount` to the index if index < 0. e.g.:  https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/11/ (migrated the setting of the index to a single function 'play' where the index is checked)

Comment: Dear @Me.Name , you added `if(v.onPlay)v.onPlay(v);` in your latest update. To me it means play videoSource[videoIndex] if  videoSource[videoIndex] is on play...and the code can still work without this condition?

Comment: Ah, I've used the second fiddle of the original post (the one with objects). In that example, functionality is added to the objects where wanted. e.g. `videoSource[3].onPlay = someFunction`. The line `if(v.onPlay)v.onPlay(v);` calls that function if set.

Comment: Hi @Me.Name , I use the method from your first file to check the index, as it's more maintainable as you said. But it doesn't work in my code. Plus I replaced the "alert" function with "display" for video titles. I tried the "setTimeout" fucntion with fadein/out for the "display" function, neither works. jsfiddle.net/nojava/7vrdx11r

Comment: The fadein and fadeout were both executed after the same delay. (the statements weren't in the same code block). If the fadeout is delayed after the fadein, the label is shown: http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/23/

Comment: Hi @Me.Name , If I hit play-next/prev button continuously/quickly for many （5-6） times, the "fadein" function for tittle will stop working temporarily, occasionally the tittle will flicker. It will go back to normal for the next video.  Please have a look at this updated vision from  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/7vrdx11r/)

Comment: The setTimeout that is called to delay the showing of the title is never cancelled (Cleartimeout) e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/33/

Comment: Hi @Me.Name , when I click the tittle, it won't open the link. If I right click and choose open in new tab, it will open the link...

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think that's because the code runs inside the jsfiddle environment (separate frame? ). You could try running it from a html file and check if it works as expected.

Comment: Dear @Me.Name , after you added "Cleartimeout" to the code, the array checking code "if([1,3,4].indexOf(vidIndex) != -1)."stopped working as well. The tittle will show up on all videos. P.S. I could open the link in one of the old vision of this code. "<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/" target="_blank">yahoo</a>" This code works in JSfiddle too.

Comment: whoops, missed some brackets after the if. settimeout is always called. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/34/   Do you have an example of the fiddle where the link worked?

Comment: Hi @Me.Name , I think I overwrote the working code. I applied you code onto a blog and the link still doesn't work. Please have a look. [link](https://blvld.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the `playing` event on the `video` element. Here is how to do that:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener("playing", play_started, false);
```

The `play_started` method will be called when a video is started. Inside that method you can check whether a specific video is being played or not. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is [an update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4qm0L6/4/).

The idea is to add dropdown list  :

```js
const videoSources =[
 'http://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/rabbit320.webm',
'http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
'https://vtt.tumblr.com/tumblr_ok41s7Iebh1t4fjz0_480.mp4', 'https://vtt.tumblr.com/tumblr_ok44bpZZka1t4fjz0_480.mp4','http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4'
];

const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.onchange = function() {
 videoPlay(parseInt(this.value))
};

videoSources.forEach(appendOption);

function appendOption(url, index) {
         const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", index);
        option.innerHTML = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        select.appendChild(option);
}



var i = 0;
var videoCount = videoSources.length;
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSources[0]);
videoPlay(0);

function videoPlay(videoNum)
{
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSources[videoNum]);
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
```

```html
<div>
<select onchange="videoPlay(parseInt(this.value))">
 
</select>
</div>
<video class="myVideo" controls autoplay muted id="myVideo">
https://jsfiddle.net/nojava/5vo8cdbr/#run</video>
```