# the play next/prev button issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, hide

When I set the tittle of the video, it appears for a few seconds, then disappears after each video has played. Everything works fine without the play-next/prev buttons. If I hit either button quickly, many times, the tittle reappears and disappears seemingly forever. Please check [the complete code from JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nojava/7vrdx11r/31/).

```js
function nextVideo(){
    $('#videotittle').hide();
    play(vidIndex + 1);
}

function prevVideo(){
    $('#videotittle').hide();
    play(vidIndex - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setTimeout that is called to delay the initial showing of the title is never cancelled (`Cleartimeout`) 
a reference to the setTimeout needs to be kept that can be cancelled e.g.:

`curTimeout =setTimeout( ....`

and on play: `clearTimeout(curTimeout);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vrdx11r/33)

PS, the fiddle is based on the older fiddle in the comments of the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789795/1431042) answer. It might be somewhat different than the new version

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add [`.stop( true, true )`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to your animation ?

Your fiddle updated :

http://jsfiddle.net/hftgmuLy/

Comment: I tried again the fadein function for tittle didn't work after the continuously quick click, and went back to normal afterwards. @QuentinRoger